# What widgets are used on a page?

Tags: widgets

I would want to get know what are the actually used widgets on the actual site. For example, I made a `/about` page with `B,C` widgets and I have `A,B,C,D,E,F`. At `wp_head` I would need to have those list, I want to add some meta data to head according to this

Answer (score 1):

This is unsolvable in general case, since widgets can be either generated by sidebar calls in arbitrary locations of templates or (rarely) even rendered individually *without* sidebar.

So for general case *at best* you can hook into the processes and run some logic at the *end* of page load.

If you are working on specific bespoke site you can be more flexible. If you *know* in advance which sidebars are expected to run on page you *could* try to examine data structures early in the load process.

You don’t provide much context, but my educated guess would be that trying to make global page context conditional on widgets somewhat goes against the whole *idea* of widgets as *contained* pieces. If I saw this in the wild my first thought would be that widgets are being over–architectured into a role they are not meant to perform.

Comment: mm isn't it exactly what `is_active_widget` does? disregarding the edge cases of a widget in a shortcode or one directly inserted in the code, it should work.

Comment: I think that one will tell you if widget is in _some_ sidebar, it cannot divine if that sidebar _runs_ on current page though? Also edge cases, that's what breaks a lot of general cases. :)

Comment: hmmm yes (writes mental note to recheck my widget detection code) but it is not like it is impossible, you just need to detect first which sidebars are active which is hard in the header but if you control the theme it should be "easy" (for some random value of it)